# Homebrew MySQL error: ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, mysql

I have installed MySQL using Homebrew on my Snow Leopard Mac OS 10.6. I have run through the commands that it mentions:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

But when I connect and try to list databases (or take any other action) I get errors:

```
$ mysql
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)
```

I tried searching for an answer to the error, but couldn't find anything to help me resolve this issue. What do I need to do to set this up correctly?

FYI: I might have manually installed MySQL at one point. Not sure if there are any remaining files that are conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I did have a previous MySQL installation that was conflicting. Looks like it was even running too.

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql
brew uninstall mysql

sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

[This tutorial](http://tomkeur.net/39/how-to-remove-mysql-completely-mac-os-x-leopard.html) helped me remove all traces of the previous installation:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostconfig
# remove this line: MYSQLCOM=-YES-

sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm /etc/my.cnf
```

Then I reinstalled MySQL through homebrew and everything is good:

```
brew install mysql
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```